# Calculate a time from file with awk

Tags: awk

I would like to calculate the response time from a file that I have. The response time will be the time between sending a packet from a source (A) until ack is received from a destination (B) by the source (A). Using awk would be the answer to extract the response time. However, I'm a bit confused on how to apply the logic. Below part of the trace file:

```
 + 0.1 6 0 tcp 40 ------- 1 6.0 2.0 0 0
 - 0.1 6 0 tcp 40 ------- 1 6.0 2.0 0 0
 + 0.101172 6 0 tcp 40 ------- 1 6.1 2.1 0 1
 - 0.102032 0 1 tcp 40 ------- 1 6.0 2.0 0 0
 + 0.102394 6 0 tcp 40 ------- 1 6.2 2.2 0 2
 .......
  .....
 + 0.112517 6 0 tcp 40 ------- 1 6.6 2.6 0 6
 + 0.122096 1 2 tcp 40 ------- 1 6.0 2.0 0 0
 .....
 r 0.148256 0 6 ack 40 ------- 1 2.0 6.0 0 7
 r 0.149428 0 6 ack 40 ------- 1 2.1 6.1 0 8
 ...
```

In this example I will focus on the communication between source (6) and destination (2). So the response time would ( 0.148256 - 0.1).

```
r 0.148256 0 6 ack 40 ------- 1 2.0 6.0 0 7
```

this line shows that the reply which is ack from 2 port 0 ($9) to 
source 6 port 0 ($10) is received, While the first line in the example:

```
 + 0.1 6 0 tcp 40 ------- 1 6.0 2.0 0 0
```

showing the request is being issued by source (6) port 0 ($9) to destination (2) port 0 ($10). 
The destination throughout the whole trace file is always (2), I was thinking something like: 
Note: each time the port( which is part of $9 or $10) number is changed, that means new request connection.

to record the time of the initiated request:

```
$1 == "+" && $5 == "tcp" && $6 == 40 && $10== 2.port && $9==source.port ) {
print $2; // would be the start 
}
```

to record the time when the reply received;

```
 $1 == "r" && $5 == "ack" && $6 == 40 && $9== 2.port && $10==source.port ) {
print $2;  // would be the end 
}
```

the expected output could be in two ways as one column:

1) based on the flow id i.e  flow 1:

```
    source: 6.0 - 2.0 ---> response time: 0.148256 - 0.1
    source: 6.1 - 2.1 ---> response time : end-start
    source: any source.port-2.port --> response time : end-start
```

My problem I'm not sure how to automate the code, so I can go over the whole trace file and store the values of response time. At the end I want graph response time. Any suggestions? don't mind other scripting language !

Comment: your good question could be made great by adding and explicitly labeling a section of "required output based on the above sample input". You might also want to tag any input lines that you would expect to be skipped with a trailing comment like '# skip'. Good luck!

Comment: sorry, I really don't get that as sample output. If you want those literal strings, just do `print "     response time\n-------------------\n      values"`. Good luck.

Comment: How big are these files?  If they aren't too big, I'd recommend using awks associative arrays (maps) by creating a key that can be produced from the start and stop lines.  Then you can store whatever value you want, say with delimeters and parse them for display in the END block.  I'll try to mock something up, but I don't quite understand your fields/requirements as the question is stated.

Comment: Please try to make long story shorter and more to the point. Explanation of data isn't necessary, but the structure.

Comment: @shellter . I mean by values as the calculated response time.@ n0741337. The files are relatively big 500M.@captcha the reason why I explained the data as the input data is not small and I thought if explain the data , might make it easy to understand. Will try to short it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay - I don't quite understand the file's mapping, but based on the example, here's one possible framwork for a solution that could work for you.

```
#!/bin/sh

awk '

$1 == "+" && $5 == "tcp" { garr[ makeKey( $4, $6, $10 ) ] = $2 }

$1 == "r" && $5 == "ack" {
    key = makeKey( $3, $6, $9 )
    if( key in garr )
        garr[ key ] = sprintf( "d%f", ($2+0.0) - (garr[ key ]+0.0) )
    }

END {
    for( key in garr )
        printf( "key = %s, value = %s\n", key, garr[ key ] )
    }

    function makeKey( arg1, arg2, arg3 ) {
        return sprintf( "%s:%s:%s", arg1, arg2, arg3 )
    }

' $1
```

There's a function makeKey() to produce keys for the global array, garr.  Whenever there's a start row, put in a value.  When there's an end row, try to compute the differences.  The difference is then stored in the same key location but with a "d" in front of it.  This kind of technique could ostensibly be used to only print differences in the END.

I stripped out the "...." lines from the input file (instead of ignoring them with awk) and put them into a file called "data".

I placed the code into in a file called "elap" and "chmod +x elap" to make it executable.  Here's an example of running it:

```
prompt> elap data
key = 2:40:2.0, value = 0.122096
key = 1:40:2.0, value = 0.102032
key = 2:40:2.1, value = 0.123268
key = 0:40:2.0, value = d0.048256
key = 0:40:2.1, value = 0.101172
key = 1:40:2.5, value = 0.112802
key = 0:40:2.2, value = 0.102394
key = 1:40:2.6, value = 0.114549
key = 0:40:2.6, value = 0.112517
```

The final output could be altered to match a format you want.  The only difference found is on the 4th line of the ouput and has "value = d0.048256" - which should be from your example case.

The key might not be complicated enough for tracking multiple instances of elapsed times between the same source and destination as it's written.

---

After the question was altered, I altered the answer, but left the original, since it shows how to produce the difference which the second script isn't doing.  Not quite sure about what's proper etiquette here.

This is "elap2" then:

```
#!/bin/sh

awk '

BEGIN { DELIM = " - " }

    # grab "start" rows, ignore them if they are already in garr
$1 == "+" && $5 == "tcp" && $6 == 40 {
    key = makeKey( $9, $10 )
    if( !(key in garr) )
        garr[ key ] = $2
    }

$1 == "r" && $5 == "ack" && $6 == 40 {
    key = makeKey( $10, $9 )
    if( key in garr )
        garr[ key ] = sprintf( "%s%s%s", $2, DELIM, garr[ key ] )
    }

END {
    for( key in garr )
        {
        value = garr[ key ]
        # get the values back out here - only print entries with elapsed times
        if( split( value, varr, DELIM ) == 2 )
            printf( "source: %s ---> response time: %s%s%s\n", key,
                varr[1], DELIM, varr[2] )
        }
    }

    function makeKey( source, destination ) {
        return sprintf( "%s%s%s", source, DELIM, destination )
    }

' $1
```

which produces the output requested:

```
source: 6.0 - 2.0 ---> response time: 0.148256 - 0.1
source: 6.1 - 2.1 ---> response time: 0.149428 - 0.101172
```

after piping it through sort.  I imagine the problem is more complicated than I've represented in this edit because of duplicate start rows based on the new key.  If there's more unique info to give each key, that would help.

Comment: That's so close framework to what I want. However, I had two issues with the code when I run it. I got an error and the code after that continues to run and produces output:line 2:$"r"command not found. This error not the issue, I can fix it. But, I need to understand the output: key = 2:40:2.0, value = 0.122096, I didn't understand the key values. I need to have key:source.port 2.port-->response time=difference. Will update the question. Thanks alot

Comment: Thank you it works. I'm still not sure why I'm getting different port number for each line i.e source: 15.738 - 2.8024. It should be the same !!!

Comment: I'm glad it works for you.  I've never seen NS2 formatted files before.  I couldn't speculate as to why the source port numbers don't line up in the original data file.  Good luck!